# Error when getting row().data() from indexed db

Tags: jquery, datatables

I tried to get the row data using
`row(index).data()`
Where index is the row index.
I get the data initially pushed to the table. But the update I do in "columnDefs" render() function is not reflected.
The value I return in render() function is reflecting in table but it is not got in row().data()

please see the screenshot value in table but it is null in the console. I have consoled row().data(). [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5IP56.png

please see I have returned value 10 for the column in "columnDefs" render() function and the value has come in table. [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9YMnq.png

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue like this.

```
columnDefs: [
{
"targets": [],
"render": function(data, type, row) {
            row[5] = row[2] * $(row[3]).val();
            return row[5];
         }
}]
```

what I did previously was like:

```
columnDefs: [
{
"targets": [],
"render": function(data, type, row) {
            value = row[2] * $(row[3]).val();
            return value;
         }
}]
```

here new value is returned and it will be visible in table but the row data wont be updated. If we update row[] array we will get the update in row().data().